# How to use controller method from lib with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am using Rails 4.2 now.

I created a module under lib directory. I want to call a maintenance method from `app/controllers/applicaiont_controller.rb`, but it was failed:

```
NoMethodError in ProductsController#index
undefined method `redirect_to` for #<...>
```

My lib's module like:

```
module One
  class Display
    response = other_method
    if response.status == 200
      data = 'OK'
    else
      redirect_to_maintencance 'Maintenance ...'
    end
    data
  end
end
```

app/controllers/applicaiont_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Other methods

  def redirect_to_maintencance(message = nil)
    redirect_to :maintencance, flash: { maintencance_message: message }
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is the error thrown by `#<ProductsController>`? If you just want another `redirect_to`ish helper, maybe you can define it in `app/helpers/some_helper.rb`.

Comment: Because I want to use that module under lib directory from products_controller.

Comment: Include the code of the `ProductsController` then. The code that you provided has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: This should be in a helper method.  Right now your code is in the class definition, so it has no way of being called. It will only execute once (when it is required in another file), and then you will probably get a bunch of name or no method errors.

Comment: @jphager2 Thank you. I have moved redirect_to method to controller. Can you write it as an answer? I will accept it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good way to use redirect method in lib module.
Move status check logic to controller or helper.

Thanks to @jphager2.